# Proving Theorem 10.3 on Steven Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, adjoint-operators

I want to prove the (3) and (4) of theorem which says $\textrm{im}(\tau \tau ^{*})=\textrm{im}(\tau )$ and $(\rho _{\textrm{S,T}})^{*}=\rho _{\textrm{T}^{\perp },\textrm{S}^{\perp }}$, here $\tau ^{*}$ is the adjoint of $\tau$ and $\rho _{S,T}$ is the projection onto $S$ along $T$, and $S^{\perp }$ is the orthogonal complement of S, the book doesn't give a proof about this and I don't know how to do it, can anyone help me, thank you in advance

[image: Theorem 10.3]

> **Theorem 10.3** Let $\tau\in\mathcal L(V,W)$, where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional inner product spaces.$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$
>
> 1. $$\ker(\tau^*)=\im(\tau)^\bot \qquad\text{and}\qquad \im(\tau^*)=\ker(\tau)^\bot$$ and so
>    \begin{gather*}
>    \tau\text{ surjective }\Leftrightarrow\tau^*\text{ injective } \\
>    \tau\text{ injective }\Leftrightarrow\tau^*\text{ surjective } 
>    \end{gather*}
> 2. $$\ker(\tau^*\tau)=\ker(\tau) \qquad\text{and}\qquad  \ker(\tau\tau^*)=\ker(\tau^*) $$
> 3. $$\im(\tau^*\tau)=\im(\tau^*) \qquad\text{and}\qquad  \im(\tau\tau^*)=\im(\tau) $$
> 4. $$(\rho_{S,T})^*=\rho_{T^\bot,S^\bot}$$

Comment: You should at least say what the theorem in question says, if you expect to get some kind of reasonable answer. Is the picture that I've included the theorem you're after?

Comment: I have proved similar results in my book on Numerical Linear Algebra. You need to think visually about the results with some diagrams. Then you will be able to prove it. Geometric intuition helps really very well.

Comment: How to understand this geometrically? @Dr.Sundar

Comment: You may read my book on Numerical Linear Algebra.. Best wishes..

Comment: Simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418974/proving-theorem-10-3-on-steven-romans-advanced-linear-algebra (where it is well off-topic).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$I figured it out, because $\im(\tau ^{*})=(\ker(\tau ))^{\perp }=(\ker(\tau ^{*}\tau ))^{\perp }=\im((\tau ^{*}\tau )^{*})=im(\tau ^{*}\tau )$ by using (1) and (2) in theorem 10.3, and $\ker((\rho _{S,T})^{*})=\im(\rho _{S,T})^{\perp }=S^{\perp}$, similarly $\im((\rho _{S,T})^{*})=T^{\perp }$, because the adjoint of the projection is also idempotent we show that it is also a projection.